# Security issue with 'paged' and 'posts_per_page' parameters taken directly from a POST request?

Tags: security

I was wondering if this poses any security risk:

```
$current_page = $_POST['page'];
$posts_per_page = $_POST['posts_per_page'];

$result = new \WP_Query([
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => ++$current_page,
    'post_type' => 'post'
]);
```

Since I take `posts_per_page` and `paged` directly from a POST xhr request, someone could enter whatever values they want.

I see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) that `posts_per_page` and `paged` are listed as `int`, but could someone use e.g. SQL injection in this case nonetheless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we have the following typecasting in the `WP_Query` class (see [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cea9e2dc62abf777e06b12ec4ad9d1aaa49b29f4/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1777-L1785)):

```
$q['posts_per_page'] = (int) $q['posts_per_page'];
if ( $q['posts_per_page'] < -1 )
    $q['posts_per_page'] = abs($q['posts_per_page']);
elseif ( $q['posts_per_page'] == 0 )
    $q['posts_per_page'] = 1;
```

and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cea9e2dc62abf777e06b12ec4ad9d1aaa49b29f4/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1792-L1795):

```
if ( isset($q['page']) ) {
    $q['page'] = trim($q['page'], '/');
    $q['page'] = absint($q['page']);
}
```

Instead of running the query for every user input, hoping the core will handle it somewhere, **validate** it beforehand and only run the query if it's of correct type and range. You could check for a positive integer here and have a max allowed value, e.g. 100, because you don't want to allow e.g. 9999999 that could seriously slow down the whole site.

Comment: Thanks! I added a check doing this: `!is_numeric($current_page) || !is_numeric($posts_per_page)`. I will also add a check for the range of the numbers.